# Expo.Fingerprint.isEnrolledAsync returns an object

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create the fingerprint authentication process on my react native app. I have used the following SDK from Expo to achieve it.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/fingerprint.html#returns-1

The Expo.Fingerprint.authenticateAsync() method suggest that it will return a boolean. However, it seems to return an object when I tried printing it out.

```
Expo.Fingerprint.authenticateAsync()
  .then(success => {
      if(result == true) {
        console.log("Touch ID success. " + result);
      } else {
        console.log("Touch ID failed. " + result);
      }
});
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem as I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returns an object with the boolean embedded in it. You can access it this way.

```
Expo.Fingerprint.authenticateAsync()
 .then(result => {
     console.log(result.success);
 });
```